# storing image in a variable and then using ajax to send data in json format

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to store image in a variable and stringify it in json  to pass it through ajax method.but getting error in storing it and and stringify it in json format.
The dynamic table i am generating like this from where we pick the image id 'flImage'  and store it in a variable var user .

```
 $("#pdfFormInsideTblRight").after("<table class='table table-bordered'><thead class='thead-inverse'><tr><th class='text-left'>Properties</th>" +
                        "<th>Detail</th></tr></thead>" +
                        "<tr><td class='text-left'><strong>Product Group</strong></td>" +
    "<td><input type='file' id='flImage' name='flImage[]' multiple /></td>
</tr></table>");
```

Now i want to store the image uploaded above in variable 'flImage', in a variable 'user' like other inputs value from textbox and lables value are stored through jquery in var 'user' as given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {
    var user = {};
                user.PRODUCT_ID = 1;
    user.REVISION = $("#Revision").text();
    user.P_GROUP = $("[id*=P_Group]").val();
    user.IMG1 = $("#flImage")[0].files;
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TDC.aspx/SaveFrmDetails",
                data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                //data:  JSON.stringify({user:user}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("User has been added successfully.");
                    window.location.reload();
                }                
            });
            return false;

     });
    }
```

But while stringifying the data in json it results in error.So any idea how to stringify image in json will be appreciatd.

Comment: Which specific error message are you getting?

Comment: @OleWolf in my ajax portion it is directly going to return false